Reorganising Data layers in Catalog pane without breaking data links using ArcGIS Pro
I am using ArcGIS Pro.
When I open my project and reorganize my data layers in the Catalog pane, it breaks the data links and the layers disappear from my project.
Is there way that I can re-organize my data in the Catalog pane while the data links automatically update to the new data location?

I believe the short answer is no. Interestingly you can rename a Feature Class and the layer in the map updates it's data source. Move it and it breaks the link which you need to reset through the layers properties.
